# Can $\mathbb{N}$ be an element of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, natural-numbers

Is $\mathbb{N}$ a element of $\mathbb{R}$
I understand that $\mathbb{N}$ ⊆ $\mathbb{R}$, but does that also imply that $\mathbb{N}$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No it does not. Similarly $\{2,3\}\subseteq \{1,2,3\}$ but $\{2,3\}\not\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Additionally, it's not so easy to come up with an example where $A \subset B$ implies $A \in B$. This would be true if $A \in A$, but that leads to issues like Russell's paradox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I will answer this question naively, ignoring the actual set theoretical constructions of either sets in question.]

No, elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are numbers, no sets of numbers. So it does not make sense to say that $\mathbb{N}\in \mathbb{R}$. But it does make sense to say that $\mathbb{N}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ because every element of the first set (every natural nubmer) is also an element of the second set (is also a real number).